# Populating highcharts with php via json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, highcharts

I have been wrestling with highcharts and json_encode via php for a few days now.  I believe I have the data formatted properly but yet the chart is not updating properly.  The category data is updated and the series data to chart the column and line data is formatted as it should be.

Can anyone help me get the rest of the way.  Here is the php script and highcharts javascript I am using.

Thank you for your help:

```
<?php          
// data feed to power dynamic charts
include_once('db_conn.php');

// get site data and store in array
$query = mysql_query("SELECT site, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, SUM(clicks) AS     clicks FROM dfa_data WHERE campaign='$campaign' and time='$time' GROUP BY site ORDER BY   impressions DESC");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows['categories'][] = $r['site'];
}

// get impression data and store in array
$query = mysql_query("SELECT site, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, SUM(clicks) AS clicks FROM dfa_data WHERE campaign='$campaign' and time='$time' GROUP BY site ORDER BY    impressions DESC");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Impressions';
$rows1['color'] = '#4572A7';
$rows1['type'] = 'column';
$rows1['yAxis'] = 1;
while($rr = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['impressions'];
}

// get ctr data and store in array
$query = mysql_query("SELECT site, SUM(impressions) AS impressions, SUM(clicks) AS clicks FROM dfa_data WHERE campaign='$campaign' and time='$time' GROUP BY site ORDER BY impressions DESC");
$rows2 = array();
$rows2['name'] = 'CTR';
$rows2['color'] = '#89A54E';
$rows2['type'] = 'spline';
while($rrr = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $ctr = number_format(($rrr['clicks']/$rrr['impressions'])*(100),2,'.',',');
 $impressions = number_format($rrr['impressions'],0,'.',',');
 $clicks = number_format($rrr['clicks'],0,'.',',');
    $rows2['data'][] = $ctr;
}

$result = array();
$result1 = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result1,$rows1);
array_push($result1,$rows2);


?>

<script>
$(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Performance by Site'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: 
        <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>
        ,
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'CTR',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Impressions',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        series: <?php echo json_encode($result1); ?>
     });
  });
</script>
```

var_dump($result) outputs the following

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["categories"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(13) "Search Medica" [1]=> string(10) "Medscape 4" [2]=> string(11) "onclive.com" [3]=> string(22) "Oncology Nurse Advisor" [4]=> string(25) "chemotherapyadvisor.com 1" } } }
```

var_dump($result1) outputs the following

```
string(7) "result1"
```

Here is the json_encode output as well for both:

json_encode $result

```
[{"categories":["Search Medica","Medscape 4","onclive.com","Oncology Nurse Advisor","chemotherapyadvisor.com 1"]}]
```

json_encode $result1

```
[{"name":"Impressions","color":"#4572A7","type":"column","yAxis":1,"data":[140521,71905,69295,68456,49487]},{"name":"CTR","color":"#89A54E","type":"spline","data":[0.11,0.04,0.2,0.09,0.05]}]
```

Comment: What do `$result` and `$result1` look like? Can you do a var_dump() from PHP and post the results?

Comment: added some additional details above.  Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem is only with getting data by ajax or something similar, because when I paste your JSON (which looks like fine) then all works properly http://jsfiddle.net/6fZcz/
So I advice to take look at console, if you receive any errors. Morever php file is at the same server as script with chart?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 10
    },
    xAxis: [{
        "categories": ["Search Medica", "Medscape 4", "onclive.com", "Oncology Nurse Advisor", "chemotherapyadvisor.com 1"]
    }],
    series: [{
        "name": "Impressions",
            "color": "#4572A7",
            "type": "column",
        //"yAxis": 1,
        "data": [140521, 71905, 69295, 68456, 49487]
    }, {
        "name": "CTR",
            "color": "#89A54E",
            "type": "spline",
            "data": [0.11, 0.04, 0.2, 0.09, 0.05]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I see that your code works in jsfiddle, but the chart is rendered without the yAxis, which you commented out to get the chart to render.  Additionally I wanted to note that I see no errors in console through Chrome dev tools.  Any idea of what to check if no errors display in console?  Lastly yes the php script and js are in the same php file on the same server so that should not be the issue either.  From what I can tell my current code is outputing "" around the series data I think this may have something to do with it.

Comment: fixed the issue.  I was using print json_encode($result1); instead of print json_encode($result1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); to output the series data. It was handling the data as a string and as a result was adding "" around the numeric data.  Thanks for your help